# Will I be charged for creating a new (second) AMI from my currently running free-tier Amazon EBS-backed instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have a running instance of an Amazon AMI instance that I've installed Node.js, modules, various updates, etc., and I would like to save a new AMI created from this instance in its current state. The current instance qualifies for the free tier. How many AMI "backups" can I make, and will it continue to be free for me?

Comment: Todd - if you have comments, post them as comments, not as part of your question. Additionally, if you want to discuss this further, open up a question over on [meta.SF](http://meta.serverfault.com/).

Comment: "You should explain your rational for how this is not related!" Generally, billing questions are best dealt with by the people who are billing you.

Comment: That is like saying, "generally technical questions are best dealt with by the people who's product you are consuming." Cute but not substantive.

Comment: Like it or not, that's the way SF tends to work. Billing questions get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Limitations on EC2 free tier usage are all spelled out for you [here](http://aws.amazon.com/free/). The item that relates to your question are that free tier usage includes:

> 30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage, plus 2 million I/Os and 1 GB of
>   snapshot storage.

Since AMIs are more or less pointers to snapshots, it's unlikely that you'll have enough space to backup your machine without being charged for it.

Comment: why did you comment and then vote to close this as off topic?!

Comment: @ToddHopkinson Would have you rather I not answered? 1) it was an easy answer, and I thought you'd appreciate having it. 2) Regardless of whether or not I knew the answer, it was still off-topic, so I voted as such. This happens **all the time**, where people VTC and then still answer.

Comment: I do appreciate it which is why I up voted your comment. Thanks.